# Adding a credit card to Stripe and Braintree concurrently

Tags: stripe-payments, braintree

I'm using Stripe.js and directly adding the customer's credit card to Stripe. I want to simultaneously use Braintree! Is there a solution where the user only needs to enter their card information once, and it gets added to both Braintree and Stripe?

Because card details aren’t accessible in stripe.js, I couldn’t try out a workaround

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Braintree, however from a Stripe perspective, this won't work with Elements or Checkout, since it only accepts a customer input on the client and will encrypt the data after submission so you can't use it afterwards in Braintree.

The only way that you could make it work with Stripe is by collecting the raw payment data yourself, and passing it to Stripe server-side - this is referred to as "API direct" here:
https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide

This integration will subject you to a lot more scrutiny than Elements or Checkout, from both Stripe and PCI authorities, as you'll need to submit SAQ forms to prove you're complying with security directives with regards to how you handle this data.

Incidentally, there is no public guide for this, you'll need to provide Stripe with a valid SAQ D before they can let you implement this.